# Мгновенно закрывается .py файл

Tags: python, файлы, консоль, input

У меня есть **.py файл**, который я хочу открыть в проводнике **двойным нажатием** клавиши, а не прямо через консоль командой - **python main.py** или другую программу. В ней есть и **input()**. При нажатии открывается консоль с программой и почему-то **мгновенно закрывается**, код даже не успевает выполниться. Раньше у меня это работало

Код программы:

```
a = int(input("Введите число: "))
b = a * 2
print(b)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123170/discussion-on-question-by----py-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла переустановка python